# Is there any way to reduce breeze.js payload sizes or should I not worry about it?

Tags: breeze

Using Breeze.js for client and BreezeController for the server, the payload sizes that it generates seem inefficient to me. For example when doing a simple paged projection of 3 properties via something like:

```
.select("Property1, Property2, Property3")
```

Each record has the following as the type:

```
"$type":"_IB_eTB9_dNYb7IWzNREO3W5Uer5DOQ8[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
```

And obviously the more properties I include in my projection the longer this will be, in many cases the type "definition" is significantly longer than the actual data and it is repeated for every row.

Am I worrying over nothing or are there any ways to reduce this?

Comment: Though it's not much of an issue because of compression they have addressed this with custom serialization. http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting question.  It's really more of an issue when you request projections (queries using the select statement) as opposed to entities because at least for a .NET server, the json serialization of an anonymous type is kind of ugly.  Take a look at the results for a query without a select and you'll see that the payload is much more reasonable.

That said, it should be possible for us to modify the default json.net formatter to simplify the serialization of anonymous type information, especially because we basically ignore it on the client anyway once the client realizes that it doesn't match any "known" type.  If this interests you please add it to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We do pay attention to these feature requests.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'll have a look at adding it to User Voice as that sounds good :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I'm going to say I shouldn't worry about this (and it probably applies to more general "metadata over the wire" concerns too)

Assuming we turn on gzip compression, my tests show that all the extraneous metadata makes very little difference to the size of the final compressed payload, which is I guess not surprising.